# Match 2 columns in excel to show value in a 3rd column

Tags: excel, indexing, matching

I've got an excel spreadsheet with 2 tabs on, the first tab has a location, location type and version number column.  The second tab has the location, location type and a blank column I want to work on.

On both tabs, the location is in there multiple times (otherwise it would be a lot simpler) and Im only working with one specific location type which hopefully will make this easier but on my main sheet, for each location there are 3 location types.

What I want to do is put the value from the version number field into my blank cell where the location and version number match up.. is it possible

Tab 1 - Location info

```
Location, location type, Version
LEEDS      Live          1.0.01
LEEDS      Test          1.1.01
LEEDS      Train         1.2.02
```

Tab 2 - issues

```
Location, Location type, Version
LEEDS, Live, (HERES WHERE I WANT THE VERSION BASED ON MATCHING A and B)
LEEDS, Live, (HERES WHERE I WANT THE VERSION BASED ON MATCHING A and B)
LEEDS, Live, (HERES WHERE I WANT THE VERSION BASED ON MATCHING A and B)
```

Theres a lot of locations but thats pretty much it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the following formula (without adding values to your table)

```
{=INDEX(Sheet1!C:C,MATCH(A2,IF(Sheet1!B:B=B2,A:A),0))}
```

The sheetnames might not be exactly what you are looking for - this assumes your lookup data in Tab2 has `A2 = "LEEDS"` and `B2 = "Live"`.

You will need to make these formulas (if in a list) array formulas by using `control+shift+enter` (on Mac substitute `command` for `control`). This makes the formula work as an array operation. [More information on array formulas](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/putting-basic-array-formulas-to-work-HA001087292.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA001087290).

---

However, one of the things I have done in these sorts of situations is make a "key" value on my main data tab which is unique. Then, instead of having to do a complicated formula (which really is more for when the spreadsheet will be maintained beyond a few days and either myself or someone else will need it) I can use a simple `vlookup` - which is much easier to understand than a combination of `MATCH` etc.

So what I would do is add a column in A for Tab 1 which is called "Key" and make this value something like:

```
= B2 & B3
```

This gives a unique key you can reference each row using.

Then, on your second tab, you can do something like

```
=vlookup(A2 & A3, Tab1SheetName!A:D, 4, false)
```

This is considerably easier to understand when you look back at this spreadsheet in several weeks/months or someone else needs to use it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help, its kind of working, when I setup a test table as above, on my maind data table theres 9 rows, 3 for each location, 3 for each location as theres a type of live test and train.  On my other tab I setup up 12 rows (4 for each location) and pasted your query.. it showed the right version on rows 1 and 4 of my top location but the rest is #N/A... I must be missing something?

Comment: @mozza54 Make sure your values are actually the same on both sheets

Comment: Theyre the same in terms of case but there are different locations and also different location types, Ive just copied and pasted 1 location 9 times and it shows the right version every 3rd row but the additional locations still arent right?

Comment: Are you dragging the formula down? IE is the input information to the formula working correctly? Btw, these sorts of issues are another reason why the second half of my post is quite useful much of the time

Comment: Yeah Im dragging it down, Its wierd as I could do this in my sleep in sql.. just cant get my head around it in excel

Comment: I did try copy and paste as well but then its trying to match different locations, what Im trying to get it to do is find the matching location and matching location type

Comment: @mozza54 are you using array calculations? Try hitting `cntrl+shift+enter` when leaving the cell. I didn't include that in my answer initially

Comment: I dont think Im using an array (Pretty sure Im not) but I did try ctrl+shift.. and it didnt help =INDEX('Site Version'!D:D,IF('Site Version'!A:A='Awaiting Retests'!A14, and 'Site Version'!B:B='Awaiting Retests'!B14),0)  I tried this (Version is in column D not c) it pulls through version numbers.. just the wrong ones, If I can get A and be so exactly match Im almost there :D